# Is there a way to 'combine' excel functions to create a reference to another cell?

Tags: excel

Just like how one might put `=B2` in a cell, B denoting column B and 2 denoting row 2 of course, I was wondering if it was possible to use a function to do the same thing.

In theory, it would look like `=B AVERAGE(A1:A10)` which would result in `B5` or something.

Is there a way in which I could do this? Thanks.

Comment: INDIRECT is what you are looking for - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Comment: @Sam As I’ve got older I’ve tried to be less dogmatic, but in this case, if you are considering using INDIRECT in any way (except possibly to generate a reference to another worksheet) then there is usually a better way. Perhaps the OP could clarify what they are trying to achieve?

Comment: INDIRECT is a perfectly good option for small and not so complex things. Once it grows, INDIRECT must go.

Comment: @Sam - put `INDIRECT()` in an answer with a short example and be done with this question already.

Comment: @DS_London  Now that I am trying to use the INDIRECT function, I think that I may have been rather unclear in my initial question. I am an excel novice, and I think I used the term 'reference' wrong here. To clarify myself, there are situations in which we put in, lets say a cell A1 ```=B1``` denoting that the value in B1 will be represented in A1. And if we assume that there is a integer of 3 in C1, what I want to do is in another cell ```= (column B) + C1``` which would result in ```=B3```, where the C1 in the function only denotes the row and (column B), column B. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: if you are trying to get the value Bn, where n is in C1, then you can use =INDEX(B:B,C1). The INDEX function is returning the value of the nth cell in column B. So if C1 contains 3, the result will be the value of the 3rd cell in column B, ie B3.

Answer (score 0):

Use the INDEX() function to extra a numbered row from a column.

eg answering *"In theory, it would look like =B AVERAGE(A1:A10) which would result in B5 or something.*"

```
=INDEX(B:B,INT(AVERAGE(A1:A10)))
```

INDEX() is a non-volatile function, and can be easily audited.

[image]